# Gcc and ld arguments

Tags: gcc, compilation, ld

how can I pass the option `--enable-auto-import` to ld from gcc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  -Xlinker option
       Pass option as an option to the linker.  You can use this to supply system-specific
       linker options which GCC does not know how to recognize.
```

Answer (score 11):

```
gcc ... -Wl,--enable-auto-import ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the -Xlinker option to [pass options to the linker](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Xlinker-970):

```
$ gcc -Xlinker--enable-auto-import blah...
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: It's rarely mentioned but if you have a linker option that requires a value, say ...

```
-current_version 1
```

... you need to do the following:

```
-Wl,-current_version,1
```

... or ...

```
-Xlinker -current_version -Xlinker 1
```